# How to integrate the curve

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, vectors, vector-fields

We have a Curve $C:\vec{x}\left(t\right)=\begin{pmatrix}1-2t^2\\ t\end{pmatrix}$ Now you have to calculate $\int _C\vec{F}\left(\vec{x}\right)d\vec{x}$ for

- $\vec{F}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$
- $\vec{F}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\ x_1\end{pmatrix}$

There are many more practice problems just like this and I'd like to try and solve them but I don't know how to start.

Do I make $1-2t^2 =1$ or $t=0$?

What does $\vec{F}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\ x_1\end{pmatrix}$ even mean?

[image: Question Pic]

Comment: there $x:=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, assuming that $F:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$, so $F(x)=F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=(x_2,x_1)$ is a function from $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^2$. By the other hand $F(x)=(1,0)$ also goes from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^2$ (it is a constant function, it maps every $x\in\Bbb R^n$ to the vector $(1,0)\in\Bbb R^2$)

Comment: seeing the definition of $x(t)$ I guess that $n=2$ for this exercise, otherwise the composition $(F\circ x)(t)=F(x(t))$ would not be defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: if you dont know the notation $f\circ g$ just mean the composition of functions $f$ and $g$, that is, $(f\circ g)(s)=f(g(s))$.*

There is something that could confuse you: the symbol $x$ is used for two different purposes in the exercise

1. to denote a vector on the domain of $F$, and
2. to denote a function from $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$.

Just substituting we have that

$$(F\circ x)(t)=F(1-2t^2,1)$$

where we assumed here that the domain of $F$ is some subset of $\Bbb R^2$ (probably $\Bbb R^2$ itself) because the image of the function $x$ is in $\Bbb R^2$.

Now, for the first case we have that $(F\circ x)(t)=(1,0)$, that is, every $t\in\Bbb R$ defines some $x(t)\in\Bbb R^2$, thus $F(x(t))=(1,0)$ because $F$ is already constant.

For the second case we have that $(F\circ x)(t)=(t,1-2t^2)$, assuming that the notation $x_k$ refer to the coordinates of the vector $x$.

Can you evaluate $\int_C F(x)\cdot dx$ in each case now?

Comment: Ok I will try to do it now. I can evaluate it in the first case. But I am still confused about the second one.

Comment: Ok I still do not understand where am I supposed to use the (1, 0). Before the integration? Will it be used to find t?

Comment: $\int _0^1-4tdt=-2$ This is what I understood from your explanation, I multiply F(x) with the derivative of x(t). Is that correct? @Masacroso

Comment: Ok nvm I could do it :) Thanks for the explanation. So for the second case it would be $\int _0^1\begin{pmatrix}t\\ 1-2t^2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-4t\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ which would then be $\int _0^1-4t^2+1-2t^2dt=-1$ No?

Comment: @Naochi we have that $$\int_C F(x)\cdot dx=\int_a^b (F\circ x)(t)\cdot x'(t)\, dt$$ assuming that $[a,b]$ is the domain of the function $x$ that parametrizes the curve $C$. Yes, what you did is right if $[0,1]$ is the domain of $x$

Comment: Not sure about the domain, we always used [0,1] with these types of integrations. Glad to know it is correct for the domain. I just hope the domain is right.

Comment: @Naochi, well, this is important. It is not the same curve if the domain is $[1,2]$ or $[0,1]$. Are you sure it is not stated in the problem? You can assume that the domain is $[0,1]$ but this is not very rigorous

Comment: It does not state the domain in the question. I added a pic of the question in my post in case I misunderstood.

Comment: @Naochi the domain seems to be stated in the pic as $[-1,1]$

Comment: Aha then it would be something like this for the 2nd case : $\int _{-1}^1-4t^2+1-2t^2dt=-2$ right? I didn't even know we were supposed to use that domain. @Masacroso

Comment: @Naochi that seems the correct thing to do. However the exercise, as stated, is not absolutely clear, but it seems that the curve $C$ is parametrized by $x:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R^2$

Comment: I have gotten a better understanding of it now. Thanks man!